# this keyword within a function of an object not returning expected value

Tags: javascript, object, this

I am new to coding and learning about the this keyword, I'm expecting the function in the stephen object to perform the calculation given to it (2022-1995) and for that result to show,  but it seems like the this keyword is not defined and I do not know why after trying to fix it for hours.

```js
const stephen = {
  firstName: 'Stephen',
  lastName: 'McColgan',
  job: 'Admin',
  friends: ['Chris', 'Simon', 'Thea', 'N/A'],
  hasDriversLicense: true,
  age: 1995,
  calcAge: function() {
    this.birthYear = 2022 - this.age;
    return this.birthYear;
  }
};

console.log(stephen.age);
console.log(stephen.birthYear);
```

Comment: You're never calling `calcAge`…?!

Comment: don't you think age and birthYears are swapped?

Comment: Sorry I just understood what you meant and yes I believe I have made a fatal and very simple oversight, sorry - I have put console.log(calcAge); but it comes back and says it's undefined. I just don't understand where I have went wrong

Comment: this would be the canonical case for a getter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: Thanks The Fool I tried your suggestion and my code is fixed now, I really appreciate you taking the time to help me here! I will try to ask better questions in the future and get better at research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not the calling the `calcAge()` function before displaying the `age`. So It is returning `undefined` cause `this.birthYear` will be initialize when you will call the function. So first you should call `calcAge()` function and the display the `age`.

---

In your case `birthYear` and `age` got swapped. Here is working code:

```js
const stephen = {
  firstName: 'Stephen',
  lastName: 'McColgan',
  job: 'Admin',
  friends: ['Chris', 'Simon', 'Thea', 'N/A'],
  hasDriversLicense: true,
  birthYear: 1995,
  calcAge: function() {
    this.age = 2022 - this.birthYear;
    return this.age;

  }
};

stephen.calcAge();

console.log(stephen.age);
```

Comment: Ah thanks so much Shrey, I was looking over my code forever and didn't see this simple mistake sadly. Sorry everyone for  asking an annoying question!

Comment: I have reviewed your answer again and now I understand what you mean by calling the calcAge function, before I only logged it to console and didn't actually call it. -- I will strive to do better research in the future and get better before I ask these questions. Sorry everyone and thanks for your help, advise and criticism.